# Crear una udf simple "ifThenElse" que sea genérica y se pueda usar en un DataFrame de Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Tengo una función así:

```
def ifThenDoubleFuncion = (cond: Boolean, eIf: Double, eElse: Double) => if(cond) eIf else eElse

def ifThenUdf = udf(ifThenDoubleFuncion)
```

La quiero hacer genérica, lo he intentando de esta forma:

```
def ifThenFuncion[T <: AnyVal](cond: Boolean, eIf: T, eElse: T) => if(cond) eIf                   else eElse
```

Pero me da un error cuando el DataFrame procesa la UDF dado que no acepta la clase AnyVal. Estoy buscando otra forma de hacerlo.

No quiero emplear pattern matching por temas de performance.

¿Alguien sabría sortear esto?

Comment: English post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40214798/create-a-simple-ifelse-generic-udf-that-works-for-all-datatypes-accepted-by-a-da

Comment: Deberias restringir los posibles valores de T

Answer (score 0):

quieres convertir una funcion en UDF, para eso deberas mejorar el codigo en cuanto a parametros

un ejemplo podria ser:

```
def ifThenDoubleFuncion (cond: Boolean, eIf: Double, eElse: Double) ={
               // tu codigo  }

 spark.udf.register("ifThenUdf ", ifThenDoubleFuncion )
```